# Quale genere ha il termine tecnico patch?

Tags: gender

Di solito cerco di usare poco termini tecnici in lingua straniera, e preferisco l'equivalente italiano. Nel caso di *patch*, inteso come file creato per risolvere uno specifico errore di programmazione, non mi vengono in mente altre traduzioni se non *pezza* o *rattoppo*, che non mi piacerebbe usare in questo contesto.
Mentre scrivevo *"la patch"* però mi è venuto un dubbio sul genere, e cercando in giro per la rete ho visto che viene usato sia il maschile che il femminile.
Qual è il genere corretto da usare?

Comment: Utilizzo sempre l'articolo femminile. Anche Zingarelli la pensa come me :) Quindi ... LA PATCH

Comment: Grazie, credo che sia ora di aggiornare il mio dizionario.

Comment: Dal momento che l'inglese *patch* significa “rattoppo”, anche nel senso informatico, non vedo perché non si possa usare anche in italiano *pezza* o *rattoppo*. Vero che l'inglese “fa più fino”. `;-)`

Comment: Giusto, @greg: dopotutto per “pezza” è anche già attestato il  «senso fig., trovare, mettere una p., riparare, rimediare in qualche modo: ormai il guaio è fatto e bisogna metterci una p.», e tanto varrebbe introdurlo nell'uso informatico.

Comment: Un termine migliore, anche se non letterale, è `emendamento`. L'emendamento legislativo funziona in modo identico alla patch, dice cosa sostituire con cos'altro, dettandone le coordinate precise.

Comment: Se il testo è destinato a un pubblico tecnico, suggerisco caldissimamente di evitare di tradurre in italiano termini tecnici convenzionali. Tecnici italiani stessi capirebbero a fatica (dopodiché morirebbero dalle risate). Una patch è patch per tutti, non rattoppo o pezza o emendamento. Se invece si sta spiegando in modo non tecnico cos'è una patch, questi termini possono essere utili.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il dizionario Zingarelli 2016, che è l'unico fra quelli che ho consultato che riporta questa parola, la dà come femminile:

> [vc. ingl., propr. ‘pezza, toppa’ ☼ 1997]
>
> s. f. inv. (pl. ingl. *patches*)
>
> ● (*inform.*) file che rimedia a un errore di programmazione del software, consentendo al sistema di funzionare correttamente in attesa di una nuova versione

Comment: I forestierismi sono materia complicata. Riporto un link all'accademia della Crusca che spiega come comportarsi in generale:

http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/genere-forestierismi

Answer (score 1):

Nel caso possa servirti, una possibile traduzione del termine è "correzione", o in maniera più generica "aggiornamento" anche se ovviamente così perde l'accezione di aggiustamento.

"Rilasciare una correzione" è una frase che ho sentito molte volte, per quanto possa sembrare strana a sentirla la prima volta.

Comment: Grazie dei suggerimenti; correzione non mi piace tanto, perché la patch è il file che si usa per effettuare la correzione, come la pezza si usa per fare una riparazione. Aggiornamento invece è un'altra cosa ancora, consiste nella sostituzione completa dei file errati, o obsoleti, con altri nuovi.

Comment: @CasaMich: Nella mia lingua (catalano) si usa il termine ["pedaç"](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peda%C3%A7_(inform%C3%A0tica)) che letteralmente sarebbe una toppa o un rattoppo.

Comment: @CasaMich Anche io mi sforzo di trovare la giusta parola italiana per i termini informatici che uso, e nel caso in cui "patch" sia usato per indicare una nuova versione che corregge un errore, concordo con Svalorzen che "correzione" è la traduzione migliore, perché penso sia ben comprensibile da qualsiasi interlocutore.

Comment: @CasaMich Beh, dipende come la vedi. Esattamente come patch, correzione può essere sia sostantivo che verbo - è l'esatto equivalente italiano del termine. Puoi correggere il software con la correzione - dove correzione va a intendere il file correttivo. You patch the software with the patch.

Comment: Ecco, file correttivo in effetti potrebbe andare bene. Il fatto è che la mia frase originale era "effettuare la correzione con la patch ..."